# PHP - Add keys to exploded multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add key names to an exploded multi-dimensional array

I've this:

```
    $datos = $_POST['dataGeneral'];

    // Detecting "<" delimiter and PHP_EOL:
    /* 
       1<1<Titulo Episodio<Descripción Episodio<http://www.google.com
       1<2<Titulo Episodio 2<Descripción Episodio 2<http://www.google.com 
    */

    $data = explode(PHP_EOL, $datos);
    $num = 0;

    foreach($data as &$val){
        $exp = explode("<", $val);
        $val = array_combine(range($num, $num+sizeof($exp)-1), $exp);
        $num += sizeof($exp);
    }

    echo '<pre>CheckDelimiter:<br/>';
        print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

[image]

This work fine, but I want to add keys to this array elements:

This is what I spected:

```
Array
(
    [post-1] => Array
        (
            [temporada] => 1
            [episodio] => 1
            [titulo] => Titulo Episodio
            [descripcion] => Descripción Episodio
            [link] => http://www.google.com
        )

    [post-2] => Array
        (
            [temporada] => 1
            [episodio] => 2
            [titulo] => Titulo Episodio 2
            [descripcion] => Descripción Episodio
            [link] => http://www.google.com
        )

)
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: quick note: you can't have two `post` keys on the same level, and you already have used the array function that you need in order to have that associative key, `array_combine`, just have a hardcoded array to be combined

Comment: Can you show us what the post data looks like?

Comment: $_POST added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the base setup of the array values you need, just use `array_combine` again.

This time using your desired assoctive keys:

```
$new_data = array();
foreach($data as $k => $val){
    $exp = explode("<", $val);
    // $val = array_combine(range($num, $num+sizeof($exp)-1), $exp);
    // instead of using numeric like above
    $val = array_combine(array('temporada', 'episodio', 'titulo', 'descripcion', 'link'), $exp);
    $new_data['post-' . ($k + 1)] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Work fine, @Ghost, thanks. I'll accept the answer in  5 minutes :)

Comment: @Ferrrmolina sure glad this helped